# Loading XRC from a string

Tags: wxpython

I would like to dynamically create the GUI from some external data source. The source will present its internal structure such as fields, including data types, initial values, min max values etc, and some actions that can be handled by the (remote) data object. The structure should be transformed to text controls and buttons which should be added and deleted from the GUI dynamically.
It's very much like using XRC to load a part of the GUI, so I was wondering if I should use XRC or code something myself. Using XRC would make testing and using alternative data sources easier. Generating XRC is rather easy. So now I have the following two questions:

1. Are there any alternatives to this idea?
2. I can not find a way to load XRC from a string since xrc.XmlResource only takes a filename as its argument. Using temporary files seems messy, so any idea how to load from a string?

Comment: Well, I did find a way to load a string with `self.res = xrc.XmlResource("")` and next doing `self.res.LoadFromString(XRC)`. However, this gives and error `2012-06-22 17:10:59.996 Python[12312:1107] CFURLCreateWithString was passed this invalid URL string`. How to get rid of that error?

Answer (score 0):

After experimenting a bit, it looks like XmlResource requires a file or file-like object. I don't know why you can't just use some files, but if that's something you want to avoid then you might be able to do it by creating file-like objects. See StringIO or http://pypi.python.org/pypi/filelike/0.3.3/

Answer (score 0):

You need to call it like this:

```
        res = wx.xrc.EmptyXmlResource() #Here it is
        res.LoadFromString(resourceText)
```

Here is an example.

```
import wx, wx.xrc

resourceText = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <resource>

<object class="wxPanel" name="MyPanel">
  <object class="wxStaticText">
    <size>80,-1</size>
    <label>Hey</label>
  </object>
 </object>
</resource>
'''


class TestFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, -1, 'Testing',
                          size=(640,480))

        res = wx.xrc.EmptyXmlResource() #Here it is
        res.LoadFromString(resourceText)

        panel = res.LoadPanel(self, "MyPanel")
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(panel, 1, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, 5)

        self.SetSizer(sizer)
        self.SetAutoLayout(True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.PySimpleApp()
    frame = TestFrame(None)
    frame.Show(True)
    app.MainLoop()
```